# Z index a draggable div with JavaScript Only

Tags: javascript

So I have created an draggable div, that I want to be on top the other divs when dragging around it on the content.

I have tried style.zindex=1 but it don't seem to solve the problem, If I do it with Jquery there is no problem, but I want to solve it by JavaScript.

Any tips ?

This is what i have come up with.

```
  function changeClass() {
            var diceClass = document.getElementsByClassName("window");
            for(var i = 0; i<diceClass.length; i++){
                var z = 10;
                diceClass[i].style.zIndex=z++;
            console.log(diceClass)
            } 
        } 
        changeClass()
```

And my Css

```
.window
{

    width               : 342px;
    height              : 182px;
    top                 : 0px;
    left                : 0px;
    position            : absolute;
    background          : url(window.png) no-repeat;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
   cursor: default;

    }
```

I created an jsFiddle.
The code is on row 31 - 42

http://jsfiddle.net/dymond/tQdFZ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a fixed jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tQdFZ/5/)

You were adjusting the z indexes with a 'click' event.  Click events don't fire until it receives both a mousedown and mouseup event.  This means the z indexes weren't actually being applied until after you stopped dragging.

Since you're already handling the mousedown event with startDrag, you can use a closure variable to keep track of the current highest z index and just increment it as you go.

```
var draggable = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable'),
    draggableCount = draggable.length,
    i, currZ = 1;


function startDrag(evt) {

    var diffX = evt.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
        diffY = evt.clientY - this.offsetTop,
        that = this;

    this.style.zIndex = currZ++;

    ...
}
```

Comment: It works almost like a charm :)
The problem is that the div is going back to original z-index. it wont stay on top.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you wanted the last selected one to stay on top.  I updated my answer and jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to declare `z` outside the for loop.

```
var z = 10;

for(var i = 0; i< diceClass.length; i++) { ... }
```

Otherwise `z` will always be ten even with the `++` operator.

Comment: I had actually tried that but still no improvement.
The div wont be on top.